# Jasper reports: positioning element on bottom of the page

Tags: jasper-reports

I wonder if it's possible to position dynamically growing (table) element to the bottom of the page? My table element is on detail band, just above the page footer band.

Basically in my case the position of the topmost row of the table would be dynamically changing all the time based on the amount of rows in the table. But I'm not sure if creating this kind of presentation is even possible with Jasper where the table would be basically "growing" from bottom to top where the last row of the table would be basically fixed to the bottom of the page, just above page footer. There would be no problem if the position of the table's topmost row would be always fixed and table would "grow normally" from the fixed top position towards the bottom of the page...

I tried setting the table's position type property to Fix relative to bottom, but after that the whole table disappeared completely. This was the only thing I was able to think of so far to solve my issue.

Comment: Is you table in the detail band?, does it need to be in the detail band? (do you have multiple tables?). The solution is different depending on this...

Comment: Yes, my table (and 2 textfields just above the table) is on detail band. I have only one table on this page. There is another detail band above this detail band containing the table, but it doesn't contain tables, just textfields. I guess my table could be placed on some other band as well, but I don't see how  refactoring it to another band would help me in keeping the table's last row fixed on bottom of the page (just above the page footer). But maybe there's is a solution....

Comment: I posted one... try it out...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe the easiest way to achieve this is to put your table in a `<groupFooter>` with `footerPosition="StackAtBottom"`

The correct way to group depends on your datasource, but  let assume you have just one table creating a dummy group.

**Example** of dummy group with table **StackAtBottom** of page

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Example2" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="ca579c38-1e4f-4993-a020-efcea9d1096e">
<style name="table"><box><pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/></box></style>
<style name="table_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF"><box><pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/></box></style>
<subDataset name="Table" uuid="982be61b-ae46-4404-a9a0-30ba13e8c414">
    <queryString language="xPath">
        <![CDATA[/report/table/entry]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="name" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[name]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="class" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[class]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
</subDataset>
<queryString language="xPath">
    <![CDATA[/report]]>
</queryString>
<group name="dummy" footerPosition="StackAtBottom">
    <groupFooter>
        <band height="29">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement key="table" style="table" x="0" y="0" width="360" height="20" uuid="53ea5a0e-1218-4150-ab5a-5f947e73b284"/>
                <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="Table" uuid="64092841-9993-4ccd-89b4-84a546c719cf">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRXmlDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("report/table/entry")]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:column width="90" uuid="4f5b1813-a9cc-4f83-9bdb-b0d8c4299133">
                        <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="20">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20" uuid="f1a97e19-e23d-40b6-ad95-10614f516db7"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{class}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="90" uuid="98cfbe63-f865-419c-ad8f-d8af2ed706ba">
                        <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="20">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20" uuid="0480f047-02ba-4ec4-b12a-ef56a3cbfee9"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                </jr:table>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </groupFooter>
</group>
<detail>
    <band height="17" splitType="Stretch"/>
</detail>
</jasperReport>
```

**Result**

[image: Result]

Comment: I tried above example, but it seems that the jrxml lines are not compatible with my band: jasper studio indicates the lines as being erroneus and if I try to save the modified jrxml, it throws my additions automatically away.  Basically I just added the following lines around my second detail band: <group name="dummy" footerPosition="StackAtBottom">
    <groupFooter> . . . . . . .                                                           </groupFooter>
</group>                                                                                                       My datasource is a col of beans.

Comment: The group goes after your queryString in main report... before all your detail bands.. I have edited the answer so you can see where the group band goes...

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. Just out of curiosity, how will jasper understand to position that group defined completely outside of the actual detail band in the correct detail band as I have many (two) of those detail bands. From the above code I don't see the link between the group definition on top and the correct detail band...

Comment: You can also created within studio, right click your report node, select add group.. dummy group is made by having nothing in groupExpression (its is executed once in report), every group can have a groupHeader and groupFooter (remove the groupHeader in this case), and select groupFooter to stackAtBottom

Comment: This dummy group will be executed after your detail band's, if you need detail after this (you need to loop on other records), you need to start using subreports. If you just have another table consider using the summary band... Basically with all the different bands you try to fit you report content in correct band... to achieve your desired layout... Personally I hate the table component, I always use subreports.. ; )

Comment: Thx, I think it's working now! I had no previous experience on jasper groups and somehow I think Jasper could do things more user friendly because it doesn't feel very intuitive that in case one needs to position element on bottom of the page, he/she needs to use groups... but, anyway, at least things are working now. One thing though still is that in case my table grows so big that it starts spanning multiple pages, the table will be printed just like before: not from the bottom of the last page to up but from the first page's topmost position to down, but I think I can live with this for now

Comment: Hi I have tried using the above solution and its worked fine, my detail band is now fix at bottom but when the list inside the band grows the band does not appear anymore at the bottom when it is in the next page. It appears on top instead.